# How do I make macro constants globally accessible in C?

Tags: c, macros, extern

I have some macro constants defined in a .c file and a .h file as follows:

```
#define LOCAL_L2_BASE_LV                                    (0x00800000UL)
```

in .c file and

```
#define FPGA_PLI_FEEDBACK_OFFSET_LV_FREQUENCY           (0x00007000UL)
```

in .h file

I would like to use these constants in a different header file. What is the best way to do so? My initial idea was to use extern in the header file I want to use the constants in, but is this valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros can not be made extern, they are not variables. They are simply textual replacements. To make macros available to other header, you need to include the header defining the macro.

Comment: But one of my macro constants are defined in a .c file. In this case just including the header file that contains the other macro definition is not sufficient. Another option would be to include the .c file that contains the macro, but I am not sure if this is valid and even if it is, if this is a safe practice?

Comment: Also can I redefine the macros I need in my current header file?

Comment: @FarhanAhmedWasim, of course, you should not include .c file! You should move macro definition from .c to approriate .h file and include it.
Yes, you can redefing macros, you can even define them if they are not yet defined. However, I doubt you need this.

Answer (score 2):

You should either put both of the defines in the header file (so that they are visible from any other source file), or define them in the source file as const-qualified variables and use `extern` in the header file to expose them to the other translation units.

The `extern` declarations in the header file would look like this:

```
extern const unsigned long k_local_l2_base_lv;
extern const unsigned long k_fpga_pli_feedback_offset_lv_freq;
```

You would then define them at the file scope of the source file with external linkage like this:

```
const unsigned long k_local_l2_base_lv = 0x00800000UL;
const unsigned long k_fpga_pli_feedback_offset_lv_freq = 0x00007000UL;
```

Comment: Note that these are not constants but rather const-qualified variables.

Comment: They are const-qualified variables, which is the closest you can get to a "constant" in C.

Comment: @martinkunev, what's the difference between two? :)

Comment: The first commenter, I guess :-)

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev No, you cannot use const variables where constants are required (which makes macros superior in this case). The other thing better than const-qualified variables is enums (where applicable).

Comment: They are interchangeable in most of the cases (except in initializers where you would need a constant expression). The OP hasn't specified his particular use case.

Comment: Const-qualified variables cannot be used for static/global variable initializations, struct declarations, case labels, in the preprocessor, enum initializations, etc.

Comment: @martinkunev, visible const-qualified variables are perfectly fine to be used in case lables. The only thing is for compiler to have a visibility on them. Can't be extern in this case.

Comment: @SergeyA "The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant expression
" C99 6.8.4.2

Comment: @martinkunev: You wouldn't normally need to have a switch statement over a set of unrelated constants. Had they been related, you would use an enum and not have that problem.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev The OP was asking "what is the best way". So other than offering solution to that particular problem, I'm also offering insight into possible pros/cons of different solutions. Other that what is said this solution has the con that if you change the type, you'll have to change it at two places. So this is not the "best and only" solution.

Comment: @SergeyA: In C++ you can use const ints in a constant expression (eg., a case label), but this is C and in C you cannot. http://ideone.com/1tOsaU vs. http://ideone.com/aH7exL

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `extern` for macros, because they are expanded before linkage.

One way is to create a header with the definitions you need and include it where you need them.

The other way is to pass the definition to the compiler like this (assuming you're using gcc):

```
gcc -DLOCAL_L2_BASE_LV=0x00800000UL source.c -o executable
```

The first solution seems better because it keeps the code in the sources (as opposed to the build process).

Additionally, in this specific case the parentheses around the value are not necessary because it forms a single token and it will be expanded as such.